# The docker image digest is different after the image is pushed to an Azure Container Registry (ACR)

Tags: podman, azure-container-registry

I have an image on my machine:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ docker image ls --digests | grep debug
MyACR.azurecr.io/argoproj/argocd  debug               sha256:1346c0c07913d4da45beef22165aea26a24aab1be34eb166183c3d31ac19e8b8  b2d78a6e9763  7 hours ago   398 MB
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

It does not exist on the ACR:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ az acr repository show -n MyACR --repository argoproj/argocd
2023-05-12 00:42:56.707823 Error: repository "argoproj/argocd" is not found. Correlation ID: d5884fbd-4804-4502-bc72-e90e1843361c.
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Let us push it:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ docker push MyACR.azurecr.io/argoproj/argocd:debug
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob ddf9aeed156d done
Copying blob e8614160d539 done
Copying blob 3ab4ff5552b4 done
Copying blob cabffe0d70ef done
Copying blob c5ff2d88f679 done
Copying blob 734db535e151 done
Copying blob ab4be5894c20 done
Copying blob d4648c3c4f4e done
Copying blob a1af47c16bf8 done
Copying blob 647b5703dc62 done
Copying blob dfb784b423af done
Copying blob 2ed7c8e88b82 done
Copying config b2d78a6e97 done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

And check the digest of the pushed image:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ az acr repository show -n MyACR -t argoproj/argocd:debug --query digest -o tsv
sha256:a54903c9c8e867b458bb6f7cb41e3b26e7abf8346b7adc7ab87ebab066b2a95b
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Notice that the `docker image ls --digests` command reports the digest as `sha256:1346c0c07913d4da45beef22165aea26a24aab1be34eb166183c3d31ac19e8b8` which is different from what I get from the ACR.

What am I missing?

P.S.

I actually use podman disguised as docker:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ cat `which docker`
#!/bin/sh
[ -f /etc/containers/nodocker ] || \
echo "Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg." >&2
exec /usr/bin/podman "$@"
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Hope it does not matter here.

**EDIT 1**

I do not think the presence of a digest means the image was pushed somewhere. Here is my evidence:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp$ mkdir 1
mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp$ cd 1
mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp/1$ vi Dockerfile
mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp/1$ cat Dockerfile
FROM busybox

mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp/1$ docker build .
STEP 1/1: FROM busybox
Resolved "busybox" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/busybox:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob a58ecd4f0c86 done
Copying config af2c3e96bc done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
COMMIT
--> af2c3e96bcf
af2c3e96bcf1a80da1d9b57ec0adc29f73f773a4a115344b7e06aec982157a33
mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp/1$ docker image ls --digests |grep af2c3e96bcf
docker.io/library/busybox                  latest              sha256:9e2bbca079387d7965c3a9cee6d0c53f4f4e63ff7637877a83c4c05f2a666112  af2c3e96bcf1  3 days ago    5.09 MB
mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp/1$
```

Comment: If we have built an image in our local machine, it doesn't contain digest until we pushed to some registry. In your post, I see the first screenshot had a digest. so I guess it has been pushed to some repo earlier. Can you provide more details on it?

Comment: @GoonaBabu - please see **EDIT 1**.

Comment: OK. In my environment, that is not happening.